# How to access Websocket Response Headers in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, websocket, http-headers, response

I need to access the response header from a javascript websocket connection.
Is there any way to access these response header?
Or at least the response code?

I only have access to the event of onclose, onerror, onopen with a few (unusable - for my purposes) properties!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't. There is no functionality for that at the moment. The point of WebSockets is not HTTP communication. HTTP is only used for the handshake.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket

Comment: Ok, thanks for that quick response!
And who specifies the code from the closeEvent? The Server? Or Browser?

Comment: The websocket server implementation