# Get full response of Websocket connect

Tags: javascript, html, ssl, websocket, http-headers

My code:

```
<script>
// Create WebSocket connection.
const socket = new WebSocket('wss://echo.websocket.org:443');

// Connection opened
socket.addEventListener('open', function (event) {
    socket.send('Hello Server!');
});

// Listen for messages
socket.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
    console.log('Message from server', event.data);
});
</script>
```

Output:

```
Message from server Hello Server!
```

My qustion is, does it possible to get the full response that include the HTTP Header and the TLS certificate?

Thank you.

Comment: Well, to say it shortly... Socket's are optimal because they have small information, which means small header. You could pass some data in its header if you wanted.

Comment: Explore `event` object..

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23011900/how-to-access-websocket-response-headers-in-javascript

Comment: WebSocket is not HTTP, it just uses HTTP to initiate a connection. Once the connection has been established, HTTP is not involved anymore.  The WebSocket API does not expose access to the initial HTTP response, the TLS information, or even the underlying socket. The message data you get from the server is the full message data that the server actually sent, minus the framing and encryption used only for transmission purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, is it possible to get the full response that includes the HTTP Header and the TLS certificate?

No, it is not.  The WebSocket interface in the browser does not expose that info.  HTTP is used to establish the initial WebSocket connection, but after that, the protocol is changed to the WebSocket protocol and HTTP is no longer used.  The browser interface to WebSockets does not expose custom headers.  You can request an URL (with protocol, port, domain, path, query string, etc...) and you can send zero or more sub-protocol strings.  That's it.

From MDN, this is the interface for establishing the WebSocket connection:

```
WebSocket WebSocket(
  in DOMString url,
  in optional DOMString protocols
);
```

Once the connection is upgraded from HTTP to the WebSocket protocol, then there are no HTTP headers any more.  That data is sent in WebSocket frames as you can see [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers#Exchanging_Data_Frames).  In that data frame format, you will get all of the payload data from that frame other than the housekeeping bytes used for delineating the frame and managing security.  There are no headers there to get.

If the connection is TLS, that is completely transparent to you and none of that information is made available either.