# Is there a way to get the Response Headers of WebSocket request?

Tags: javascript, websocket

On a **Network** tab (Chrome browser) we can see a **Headers** tab.

Further if we have a request list we see *General*, *Response Headers* and *Request Headers* lists.

For example:

**General**:

Request URL: wss://some.url.com/websocket

Request Method: GET

Status Code: ...

**Response Headers**:

***OWN-KEY-FROM-SERVER: true***

etc...

---

If that was a **XMLHttpRequest**, we can use **getAllResponseHeaders** method of xhr, but WebSocket doesn't have something like this according to the WebSocket API.

I need to get from server some trigger and he is inside Responses Headers list.

Maybe somebody know a decision with that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access Websocket Response Headers in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23011900/how-to-access-websocket-response-headers-in-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

If using chrome is not the only option for you, then:

I used wireshark to manitor my websocket traffic. It included all the headers and bodies and works perfectly. Just set filter for `tcp.port==YOUR_PORT || (websocket)` and start manitoring.